# Can you create a calendar in Teams with data from an Excel Power Query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, calendar, microsoft-teams, power-query

I currently have a Power Query that compiles data on deliverables (projects, document numbers, titles, due dates, etc.) from multiple worksheets. Is it possible to use the data from the Power Query to create a calendar in Teams that would display the deliverables on the day they're due?

Apart from spending time googling various iterations of the above question, I haven't tried anything as yet because I'm kind of flying blind. Hoping that someone can either let me know that it flat-out can't be done, or if it is possible, point me in the direction of where I should focus my effort going forward.

Comment: I'm going to say no, you can't get power query to interact with a teams calendar. You might be able to use VBA/Office scripts/Power Automate to interface between excel and teams. I'm thinking the solution would be some type of sharepoint calendar that is connected to teams. But this would require migration of your excel calendar.

Comment: @gns100 - I had a feeling it wouldn't be a simple thing, and any possible solution sounds complicated enough that the time investment wouldn't justify the end result. Thank you for taking the time to reply.